# NSubstitute with DbConnection

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit, nsubstitute, dbconnection

I need to pass the DbConnection to my class.
For that I am using the NSubstitute.
But when I run the test the following error occurs:
"System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Dapper"

My Test

```
public class SceneApplicationServiceTest
{
    private readonly DbConnection _connection = Substitute.For<DbConnection>();
    ISceneApplicationService _sceneApplicationService;

    public SceneApplicationServiceTest()
    {
        _sceneApplicationService = new SceneApplicationService(_connection);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task ShouldBePossibleSuccessfullyGetByProgramScript()
    {
        const long programId = 1;
        const string scriptId = "2";            

        await _sceneApplicationService.GetByProgramScript(programId, scriptId);

        await _sceneApplicationService.Received(1).GetByProgramScript(programId, scriptId);
    }
}
```

My method

```
 public class SceneApplicationService : ISceneApplicationService
{
    private readonly DbConnection _connection;
    
    public SceneApplicationService(DbConnection connection)
    {
        _connection = connection;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<LegacySceneResponse>> GetByProgramScript(long programId, string scriptId)
    {
        object parameters = new 
        {
            CodigoPrograma = programId,
            CodigoRoteiro = scriptId
        };

        if (!ObjectValidation.IsInvalidAnyNullOrEmpty(parameters)) ;

        return await _connection.QueryAsync<LegacySceneResponse>(GetScenesByScriptAndProgram.Query, parameters);
    }}
```

The error occurs when the test tries to run the "QueryAsync"

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Jorge! You can't use `_sceneApplicationService.Received(1)...` here because `_sceneApplicationService` is not a substitute. I recommend adding [NSubstitute.Analyzers](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/nsubstitute-analysers/) to your test project which will help pick up cases like this.

Answer (score 0):

look here, its the moq for dapper extensions:

https://github.com/UnoSD/Moq.Dapper

QueryAsync is the extension method from Dapper nuget.